# display result from 2 table

Tags: php, mysql

I am working for small project, the main idea of the project to display 
some tours:

> DB - Database consist of 2 table like below

The first table consist of 4 raw:

```
id , tour_id , tour_name, image
```

and the second table for each tour details like destination and places

and raw is:

```
id , tour_id , from , to
```

The main page is done, I can display information of tour with images and url link to details page like `www.domain.com/tours/get_tour?=1`
where `1` is the `tour_id`.

My question is how can I show the information from the second table with respect `tour_id`?

I am working in PHP and HTML and MYSQL.

Comment: You'll need to join the tables with the IDs, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: The idea at SO is that you code it, and if it does not work you ask for help and we help you fix it. We dont write it all for you

Comment: dear @RiggsFolly thanks lot ya i write the code but it's not work well , let try again and i will post here again

Comment: We don't mind if your code is low-quality/broken -- we still want to see it.  Sometimes your attempt is closer than you think and we only have to offer a minor adjustment to get your code working.  Always, always post your efforts.

Comment: @mickmackusa hi thank i will do later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `JOIN` function of mysql. The use this type of SQL script with PHP:

```
    $sql="SELECT first.tour_id, first.tour_image, second.tour_id 
    FROM first
    JOIN second ON first.tour_id=second.tour_id;";
    $results=$conn-->$sql; //with $conn your connection variable
    $get_tour = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

In this way you can get first.tour_name and second.from/to depending on tour_id
Then run a while to export your datas in PHP.

$get_tour is now populated. To call elements, use

```
$get_tour['first.tour_id'];
$get_tour['second.from'];
...
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Please read RiggsFolly's comment.  (many of us _could_ have posted an answer here)

Comment: @mickmackusa Guess we are never going to stop the rep hounds

Comment: OP has been a member for 5 year, and this is the only question or answer. I would guess he get's what he wants and then deletes his questions.... Without bothering to upvote or accept an answer as a thank you.